# PHP regex: match lines that do not start with an HTML tag?

Tags: php, html, regex

This problem seems simple enough, and yet I cannot come across an example of it on the web...

I am trying to create a preg_replace that takes a line at a time, and puts `<p>` tags around it if it **does not** begin with an HTML character already.

For instance,
*this paragraph* becomes `<p>this paragraph</p>`

while

`<code>this content</code>` remains the same, with no `<p>` tags being put around it.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try a `(?!..)` [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after the `^` line start marker:

```
$text = preg_replace('#^(?!<[a-z]).*$#m', '<p>$0</p>', $text);
```

It doesn't test for a complete tag however. It assumes a tag is present when it sees `<x` already.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `^(?!<[a-z])` over `^([^<].)`?

Comment: No, that would be an option too for this simple task. The assertion checks two leading characters, so is a tiny bit more specific. But it's only a best guess approach in either case.

Comment: That's the term I was missing, "negative assertion" ... I couldn't figure out how to say: match a line that _doesn't_ begin with a certain character... thanks for the help